# Loop through a list in Python, increasing the values whilst also moving through the list on each iteration

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop, iteration

Here is my code, which is used to provide row numbers in excel:

```
clusters = 3
rowRef = [9, 12, 15]

x = 1
while x < clusters:
    rowRef[x:] = [a + 1 for a in rowRef]
    x = x + 1
```

The output I'm looking to achieve is:

- 1st Loop: [9, 12, 15]
- 2nd Loop: [9, 13, 16]
- 3rd Loop: [9, 13, 17]

So with each iteration of the loop it changes one less item from the list. However, the output I get is:

[9, 10, 10, 11, 14, 17]

What do I need to change for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lack one more slicing on your list comprehension:

```
rowRef[x:] = [a + 1 for a in rowRef[x:]]
```

Otherwise, you are iterating through the whole list instead of the remaining list to process each time.

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/SubtleUnitedStartup)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a mathematical shortcut to achieve your desired output with more efficient code.

```
rowRef = [9, 12, 15]

for i in range(1, len(rowRef)):
  rowRef[i] += i

print(rowRef)
```